# Units in Bohr's model of an atom

Tags: atomic-physics, dimensional-analysis, units, atoms, si-units

In the Bohr model the values of the orbital kinetic moment and of the allowed
radii are quantized according to :
$$mv_nr_n = n \hbar, \, r_n = \frac{n^2 \hbar^2}{me^2}$$
By combining the two, i get : $$v_n = \frac{e^2}{n \hbar} = [ C^2 s^{-1}kg^{-1}m^{-2}]$$
Now, dimensional analysis gives me a nonsensical unit, as Coulombs would have to be in $kg\cdot m^3 $ in order to have units of speed.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the fact that the potential energy in the model is $(-e^2/r)$ you can get that $[e]=[({\rm Energy} \cdot {\rm distance})^{1/2}]$ so $[e^2/\hbar] = [({\rm Energy}\cdot {\rm distance})/({\rm Energy}\cdot{\rm time})] = [v]$ and all checks out. This is $[e]$ in [cgs units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units).

Comment: Now i don't understand why $-e^2/r$ can have the right units ! If $e$ is in Coulomb and $r$ in meters, how can you equate it to Energy ? Is it a case of : "Experimentaly we see this behaviour ?

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb (or, to quote from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant : "In electrostatic cgs units, the unit of electric charge, the statcoulomb, is defined so that the Coulomb constant, ke, or the permittivity factor, 4πε0, is 1 and dimensionless.")

Answer (score 3):

When you see $e^2$, it really means $\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$, because the *Coulomb constant* $k_C:=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ is analogous to *Newton's constant* $G$, also often set to $1$.

Elsewhere, you'll see $e^2$ instead mean the fine-structure constant $\alpha=\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c\hbar}$, viz. $\alpha=e^2$ (especially when working with Feynman diagrams).

Indeed, writing everything in terms of $\alpha$ tidies things up a bit: $v_n=\frac{\alpha c}{n},\,r_n=n^2a_0$ with $a_0:=\frac{\hbar}{m_ec\alpha}$ the Bohr radius. This makes the energy $E_n=-\frac{\alpha c\hbar}{2r_n}=-\frac{m_ec^2\alpha^2}{2n^2}$.